# How to record IOS screen programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, screen, recording

Is there any way to record IOS screen programmatically. Means whatever activity you are doing like clicking buttons, Scrolling tableviews.

Even if a video is playing that will be captured again along with some other activity?

Have tried these

1. https://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos
2. https://github.com/alskipp/ASScreenRecorder

but with these libraries won't provide quality video. I need quality video.

The issue is that with video playing in the background when i capture screen it does not show smooth video. It shows like one frame of video and then after 3-4 secs 2nd frame and so on. Also quality of video is not good its blurred

Comment: The sample videos produced from the second library seem fine to me. Please explain in more detail what the issue is

Comment: The issue is that with video playing in the background when i capture screen it does not show smooth video.
It shows like one frame of video and then after 3-4 secs 2nd frame and so on. Also quality of video is not good its blurred. Can you please tell which library you use?

Comment: And one more issue i am experiencing with ASScreenRecorder that it only record for 2 secs , i am not sure why !!

Comment: Also i am getting crash at this code in ASScreenRecorder.m file --> BOOL success = [_avAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer withPresentationTime:time];

Comment: This is not how you use stackoverflow. You are asking for many different things in one question. Either edit this question or delete it and add a new one adding all of these details: 1. A clear description of what you are trying to achieve. 2. Sample code that demonstrates an attempt to do this. 3. A list of problems / errors with this approach. 4. Any relevant console logs or errors. "I'm getting a crash" is not anything anyone can help you with, we need to know the error, where it is and to see the code around it. This question currently has several votes to close it due to these issues

Comment: ASScreenRecorder works great for me. I had to update it a bit since ALAssetsLibrary is deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

As of iOS 9, it looks like ReplayKit is available to greatly simplify this.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/replaykit

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-an-introduction-to-replaykit--cms-25458

**Update**:  This may be less relevant now that iOS 11 has a built-in screen recorder, but the following **Swift 3** code worked for me:

```
import ReplayKit

@IBAction func toggleRecording(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let r = RPScreenRecorder.shared()

    guard r.isAvailable else {
        print("ReplayKit unavailable")
        return
    }
    
    if r.isRecording {
        self.stopRecording(sender, r)
        
    }
    else {
        self.startRecording(sender, r)
    }
}

func startRecording(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem, _ r: RPScreenRecorder) {
    
    r.startRecording(handler: { (error: Error?) -> Void in
        if error == nil { // Recording has started
            sender.title = "Stop"
        } else {
            // Handle error
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")
        }
    })
}

func stopRecording(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem, _ r: RPScreenRecorder) {
    r.stopRecording( handler: { previewViewController, error in

        sender.title = "Record"
        
        if let pvc = previewViewController {

            if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad {
                pvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
                pvc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect.zero
                pvc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
            }

            pvc.previewControllerDelegate = self
            self.present(pvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
    })
}

// MARK: RPPreviewViewControllerDelegate
func previewControllerDidFinish(_ previewController: RPPreviewViewController) {
    previewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: That's useful, thanks. I tried on an iPad Pro and it's perfect. Worth noting that ReplayKit won't work in older devices like the iPhone5 (isAvailable=false). I also tried in the Simulator, where isAvailable is true, but stopRecording never calls the completion callback in the Simulator (iOS 11.4, Xcode 9.4.1). There's a thread about similar problems here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87007

Comment: It's been a while, but just in case it helps, this solution works perfectly in iOS 14 /Swift 5. Just make sure to import ReplayKit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check out ScreenCaptureView, this has video-recording support built-in (see link).

What this does is it saves the contents of a UIView to a UIImage. The author suggests you can save a video of the app in use by passing the frames through AVCaptureSession.

I believe it hasn't been tested with an OpenGL subview, but assuming that it works you might be able to modify it slightly to include audio and then you'd be set.

AVCaptureSession Sample

[AVCaptureSession Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    let stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    var error: NSError?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices().filter{ $0.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) && $0.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back }
        if let captureDevice = devices.first as? AVCaptureDevice  {

            captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: &error))
            captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
            captureSession.startRunning()
            stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]
            if captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
                captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
            }
            if let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) {
                previewLayer.bounds = view.bounds
                previewLayer.position = CGPointMake(view.bounds.midX, view.bounds.midY)
                previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                let cameraPreview = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height))
                cameraPreview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                cameraPreview.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"saveToCamera:"))
                view.addSubview(cameraPreview)
            }
        }
    }
    func saveToCamera(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
            stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection) {
                (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)
                 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage(data: imageData), nil, nil, nil)
            }
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this also Since i am new so Stackoverflow limit me to post 2 links only.
https://github.com/gabriel/CaptureRecord https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/StopNGo/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: You can use default iOS framework called AVFouncation framework instead of Thirdparty ones
http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/camera/record-video-with-avcapturesession-2
https://dannygtech.wordpress.com/2014/03/04/custom-camera-on-ios-avcapturesession-avcapturevideopreviewlayer-tutorial/

Comment: And one more issue i am experiencing with ASScreenRecorder that it only record for 2 secs , i am not sure why !!

Comment: Its updated very long back... instead of Third party, pls try apple's framework

Comment: I don't want to record camera instead i want to record screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [screen-cap-view](https://github.com/adam-roth/screen-cap-view) library written in Objective-C to record a view. To use it in Swift:

- Drag and drop the .m and .h files in your Xcode project.
- Make a header file and import the file: `#import "IAScreenCaptureView.h"`.
- Then give a View this class from the PropertyInspector and make an `IBOutlet` for that view: `@IBOutlet weak var contentView: IAScreenCaptureView!`
- Start and stop the recording of the view:

  - `contentView.startRecording()`
  - `contentView.stopRecording()`