# How to show screen recording permission programmatically using SwiftUI?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I am trying to get access the screen recording permission on **Mac** using

```
if CGRquestScreenCaptureAccess(){
    print("Permission Granted")
}else{
    print("Permission is not granted")
}
```

Unfortunately, this code shows only one time permission but it does not show again.

Comment: If permission was granted, there is no need to show the message again.  Do you mean that if permission is denied, the permission message does not show again?

Comment: Yes @JWWalker, I want to verify in case if the permission not granted

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that ReplayKit works with the latest version of Swift and iOS, but ReplayKit might be what you're looking for.

Have a look at:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit
- https://github.com/alskipp/ASScreenRecorder
- [How to record IOS screen programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38322853/how-to-record-ios-screen-programmatically)

Comment: the question is tagged macOS, not iOS

Comment: I want solution for mac using SwiftUI @Tanislav

Comment: Sorry for not seeing you needed help with macOS! Although, ReplayKit is available as of macOS11.0+!